# Evaluation in continuous optimization problems

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to understand continuous optimization algorithms applied on some test functions.

Here are the results obtaind by some algorithms used for this issue on some of test functions :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFKcz.png)

I didn't understand the difference between the two underlined phrases. would you please help me in this?

P.S. sometimes they use the term (median number) instead of (mean number ) what's the difference between the two??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question lacks some context. It would have been better to link to th text too to get a grasp of what is going on.

But i read it as this (and i think that's how someone with some experience in optimization-algorithms would read it; you have to check it though with your knowledge of the context):

- The bold **1.0**s are the *normalized number of function-evaluations* on different functions to optimize (each row is a different function)

  - The values in the brackets are *unnormalized numbers* explaining the same
- When **ACO** used `820 evaluations` (unnormalized), normalized to `1.0`, **CACO** used `8.3 * 820 evaluations`

The mean and median are two different measures of central tendency. Check [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average) out to understand the differences.

Comment: I think you're right, after reading your response i've read and read again the explanation of the author and I've understood the same thing as what you say, thanks a lot for your help :)